# Не работает Post Processing для UI unity2d

Tags: unity3d, ui

Моя игра состоит полностью из UI элементов(визуальная новелла). Хотел добавить эффект виньетки на пост обработке, но она не в какую не хочет работать.
Вроде как все советы из интернета учел:

Изменил в канвасе рендер мод на Screen Space - Camera
В Camera->Rendering поставил галочку на пост процессинг
Post Processing Volume вешал и на камеру и на пустой объект
В Post Processing Layer указал Layer UI,Post Processing
В настройках URP HDR включено

Пост обработка так и не включилась. Подскажите, что упустил?

Настройки камеры
[image]

Настройки объекта с Post Processing Volume
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]